# asp.net pass variable from code behind to .aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I guess I'm missing something here, but I can't find a way to pass a simple variable from my code behind file to the .aspx page.

In code behind I have:

`Dim test As String = "test"`

and in my aspx page I try: `<%=test %>`

that gives me the following error:
`Error  2   'test' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level`

Am I forgetting something here?

Answer (score 8):

Declare `test` as a property (at the class level) instead of a local variable, then refer to it as you currently do in your markup (aspx).

VB.NET 10 (automatic properties):

```
Protected Property test As String = "Test"
```

Pre-VB.NET 10 (no support for automatic properties)

```
Private _test As String
Protected Property Test As String
Get
     Return _test
End Get
Set(value As String)
     _test = value
End Set
End Property
```

With the property in place you should assign a value to it directly in your code-behind.

Comment: What are the advantages of declaring a property instead of a field? I don't see any if there is no logic necessary for get and/or set.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **protected** modifier.

```
Protected test As String = "test"
```

Comment: do you have more info on this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

`Protected test As String = "test"` (in .vb file)

`<%=Me.test%>` (inside the markup)

EDIT: As suggested by @Ahmed, it is better to create a property instead of a variable such as the one I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to...

```
Public test As String = "test"
```

then it should work.

From here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx ...

> At the module level, the Dim statement without any access level keywords is equivalent to a
>   Private declaration. However, you might want to use the Private keyword to make your code 
>   easier to read and interpret.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable either `protected` or `public`:

```
Protected  test As string = "test"
```

And in .aspx file:

```
<%=test%>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)